# glmer model error: variable lengths differ

Tags: regression, mixed-models

I aim trying to run the following model:

```
glmer(c(EMERGED.COUNT,NOT.EMERGED.COUNT) ~ SPECIES*SOIL*TREATMENT + (1|ID), data = data_emerged_success, family=binomial)
```

I receive an error message of:

*Error in model.frame.default(data = data_emerged_success, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'SPECIES')*

I have checked my data and all variables are of equal length and there are no NA values. If I change the order of variables in the model (e.g, treatment first), I will get the same error message but for the first variable of the three.

Comment: used "glmer(*cbind*(...." instead of  "glmer(*c*(..." and everything worked as expected